# c# wraps c++ function and throws access.violation.exception

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper, access-violation

I have a wrapper in C# for C++ functions which works without any errors in 32 Bit. The function detects something in an image so my C# pseudocode looks like this.

```
void detect(image, detections){
detectCpp(ref image, ref detections);
}
```

When I compile the code in 64 Bit it will be automatically catched by the C++.dll, but gives me no detected objects. If I create a C++ library with a function detectcCppBridge, which calls the detectCpp function and use the new function/library instead, I obtain the following error:

"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

The call stack would look like detect-->detectCppBridge-->detectCpp:

When I put a cout into the detectCppBridge, the Error does not occur and everything works fine. Even when I somehow use the image in the detectCppBridge, like changing one pixel, the error does not occur.

I think that the garbage collector of C# throws the image away and the C++ functions want to access it, though it is not there anymore. I tried using GCHandle.Alloc(image) with normal and pinned handletypes, but it did not work. 
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried assigning the object to another variable, on the C# side? Garbage collection should not destroy anything that you are still using.

Comment: There is not enough information for us to help you. All we can do is guess. My guess is that your library is at fault. Without an [mvce] is is impossible to say.